# gcc undefined reference to gd functions

Tags: gcc, gd

I'm trying to compile a program, but I get the following error when I run `make install`.

```
gcc -fPIC -O3 -g -O2 -o treeviewer -L/usr/include -lm -lpng -ljpeg -lgd treeviewer.o tree.o fileio.o tree.o: 
In function `drawImage':
/home/localadmin/codehop-dev/i-codehop/treeviewer/tree.c:587: undefined reference to `gdFontMediumBold'
/home/localadmin/codehop-dev/i-codehop/treeviewer/tree.c:587: undefined reference to `gdImageString'
/home/localadmin/codehop-dev/i-codehop/treeviewer/tree.c:602: undefined reference to `gdImageLine'
/home/localadmin/codehop-dev/i-codehop/treeviewer/tree.c:610: undefined reference to `gdImageLine'
/home/localadmin/codehop-dev/i-codehop/treeviewer/tree.c:620: undefined reference to `gdImageFilledRectangle'
tree.o: In function `TreeToImage':
/home/localadmin/codehop-dev/i-codehop/treeviewer/tree.c:477: undefined reference to `gdFontMediumBold'
/home/localadmin/codehop-dev/i-codehop/treeviewer/tree.c:526: undefined reference to `gdImageCreate'
/home/localadmin/codehop-dev/i-codehop/treeviewer/tree.c:527: undefined reference to `gdImageColorAllocate'
/home/localadmin/codehop-dev/i-codehop/treeviewer/tree.c:528: undefined reference to `gdImageColorAllocate'
/home/localadmin/codehop-dev/i-codehop/treeviewer/tree.c:529: undefined reference to `gdImageColorAllocate'
/home/localadmin/codehop-dev/i-codehop/treeviewer/tree.c:530: undefined reference to `gdImageColorAllocate'
/home/localadmin/codehop-dev/i-codehop/treeviewer/tree.c:531: undefined reference to `gdImageColorAllocate'
tree.o:/home/localadmin/codehop-dev/i-codehop/treeviewer/tree.c:532: more undefined references to `gdImageColorAllocate' follow
tree.o: In function `TreeToImage':
/home/localadmin/codehop-dev/i-codehop/treeviewer/tree.c:548: undefined reference to `gdImagePng'
/home/localadmin/codehop-dev/i-codehop/treeviewer/tree.c:552: undefined reference to `gdImageDestroy'
/home/localadmin/codehop-dev/i-codehop/treeviewer/tree.c:543: undefined reference to `gdImageJpeg'
tree.o: In function `printTreeInfo':
/home/localadmin/codehop-dev/i-codehop/treeviewer/tree.c:642: undefined reference to `gdFontMediumBold'
tree.o: In function `drawImage':
/home/localadmin/codehop-dev/i-codehop/treeviewer/tree.c:627: undefined reference to `gdImageRectangle'
/home/localadmin/codehop-dev/i-codehop/treeviewer/tree.c:624: undefined reference to `gdImageFilledRectangle'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [treeviewer] Error 1
```

I have installed the `libgd` using the commmand `sudo apt-get -y install libgd2-xpm-dev build-essential`. The folder `/usr/include` has the file `gd.h`. Could anyone tell me what am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to list the directory where `libgd.a` is located with `-L` if it's not in the default directory list for gcc.

Comment: I did list that directory as well and rerun the make file, but still the same result. 
`gcc -fPIC -O3 -g -O2 -o treeviewer -L/usr/include -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lm -lpng -ljpeg -lgd  treeviewer.o tree.o fileio.o`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by changing

```
gcc -fPIC -O3 -g -O2 -o treeviewer -L/usr/include -lm -lpng -ljpeg -lgd treeviewer.o tree.o fileio.o tree.o
```

to

```
gcc -fPIC -O3 -g -O2 treeviewer.o tree.o fileio.o tree.o -L/usr/include -lm -lpng -ljpeg -lgd -o treeviewer
```